# libimobiledevice with iOS 10 and Ubuntu giving TLS error

Tags: ios, iphone, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ios10

I'm trying to copy the photos off my iPhone 5S. When I plug in my phone (I have the screen unlocked), I get an "Unhandled Lockdown error" and also when I try to use the File browser. I've seen -3 and -16 (and maybe -5 and -20, not sure).

I have tried using some of the idevice* command line tools but with very limited success: `idevicepair pair` works, as does `idevicepair validate`. But `ideviceinfo` fails with `GnuTLS error: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.`

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and iOS 10. This is a new problem since upgrading to iOS 10.

Comment: which operating system are you using? windows mac or linux?

Answer (score 2):

You must compile it yourself, as it has not been updated in the repos. 
https://gist.github.com/Aaahh/1e354ee60dbe40f64efe7e4f98f720d4

Comment: any tutorial to make this in windows?